# Не заполняется окно потоков MSVS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

При запуске приложения, у которого более 20 работающих потоков, окно "Потоки" (Отладка->Окна->Потоки) ничего не выводит. Оно пустое.

команда "~" говорит что нет потоков:

```
 >~
 Нет потоков.
 >~*kb
 Стек вызовов недоступен в данный момент.
 >~*k
 Стек вызовов недоступен в данный момент.
```

Пересобирал проект, перезапускал студию, перезагружал пк - ничего не изменяется.

Есть какие-то варианты кроме переустановки студии?

P.S. C# + WinForms, если это поможет

Comment: А вы точку останова не забыли поставить? Или хотя бы "паузу" нажать?

Answer (score 1):

Окно «Потоки» не показывает ничего, если программа запущена и не приостановлена (либо через кнопку «Пауза», либо при остановке в точке останова, либо при пошаговом пробеге).

Скорее всего, вам нужно просто остановить программу.

---

<sup>(вынесено из комментариев)</sup>